# Specific width for each point in a column/bar chart

Tags: highcharts

Is there a native way to have a column chart with each column having a different width? It should be simple enough to define a 'width' property for each point, but it apparently doesn't exist :(

I only found this solution: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=6401, but it's a not very pure... Does someone know if Highcharts team plan to work on it?--Should be very useful in many cases.

Comment: We don't have plans for this right now, what you can do is create idea here, and vote for it [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general)

Comment: Done it, thanks! http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/3830811-specific-width-for-each-point-in-a-column-bar-char